# discord.py not responding to any commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I followed a tutorial to make add a basic music function to a discord bot, but it doesnt respond to any commands. I get the "henlo frens i is alieving" message as to indicate that the bot is ready, and there are no errors showing up. But then when i try to use the ping command i get no response, and nothing shows up in the terminal unlike the other bots i've written.

````
from plznodie import plznodie
from discord.ext import commands
import music
import time


#vars
cogs=[music]
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!" , intents=intents)
intents.members = True
activvv = discord.Game("you guys complain")

#config 
for i in range(len(cogs)):
  cogs[i].setup(client)


@client.event
async def on_ready ():
  await client.change_presence(status = discord.Status.online, activity = activvv)
  print("Henlo frens i is alieving")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    before = time.monotonic()
    message = await ctx.send("Pong!")
    ping = (time.monotonic() - before) * 1000
    await message.edit(content=f"Pong!  `{int(ping)}ms`")
    

client.run("TOKEN")```
````

Comment: `@client.command()` with parens?

Comment: Do you have an `on_message` statement in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't `change_presence` (or make API calls) in `on_ready` within your Bot or Client.
Discord has a high chance to completely disconnect you during the READY or GUILD_CREATE events (1006 close code) and there is nothing you can do to prevent it.

Instead set the `activity` and `status` kwargs in the constructor of these Classes.

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", activity=..., status=...)
```

As noted in the docs, `on_ready` is also triggered *multiple* times, not just once.

I can further confirm this because running your code snippet (without `on_ready` defined) on my machine actually worked :
[image: result]

Comment: I want to mention that the latency value is very incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

to process commands you need to add on_message function

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    await client.process_commands(msg)
```